# How to insert varchar variable in dynamic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with a select statement in a loop and at the same time I want to insert a `varchar` variable and selected value into a temporary table, but I get an error like:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid column name 'SP419001_SID'

This `SP419001_SID` is the value contained in the `varchar` variable `@dbName`.

This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempCounter 
(
    dbName1 varchar(max), 
    counterNumber1 int
)

DECLARE
    @counter INT = 1,
    @max     INT = 0,
    @dbName  VARCHAR(100),
    @count   INT = 0,
    @SQLTEXT VARCHAR(MAX),
    @counterNumber VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @max = COUNT(id) FROM #tempPnamePadd

WHILE @counter <= @max
BEGIN
    SET @dbName='';

    -- Do whatever you want with each row in your table variable filtering by the Id column
    SELECT @dbName = name 
    FROM #tempPnamePadd
    WHERE Id = @counter

    PRINT @dbName

    SET @SQLTEXT    =
    --SELECT distinct PN.NAME_FORMAT_CODE, NAME_BUSINESS, INDIVIDUAL_FIRST, A.ADDRESS_ID, A.ADDR_LINE_1, A.ADDR_LINE_2, A.ADDR_LINE_3, A.CITY, A.STATE
    'DECLARE @dbn VARCHAR(200)
    SET @dbn ='+ @dbName +';
    INSERT INTO #tempCounter 
    (dbname1, counternumber1)
    SELECT @dbn ,
         (SELECT  count(*)
                                FROM '+ @dbName +'.dbo.PRELA PR  
                            INNER JOIN '+ @dbName +'.dbo.PNAME PN  
                            ON PR.NAME_ID = PN.NAME_ID  
                            INNER JOIN '+ @dbName +'.dbo.PNALK NK  
                            ON PN.NAME_ID = NK.NAME_ID  
                            INNER JOIN '+ @dbName +'.dbo.PADDR A  
                            ON NK.ADDRESS_ID = A.ADDRESS_ID  
                            WHERE (NAME_FORMAT_CODE=''B'' and NAME_BUSINESS like ''%BN'') OR
                            (NAME_FORMAT_CODE <> ''B'' and INDIVIDUAL_FIRST = ''John'') OR
                            (ADDR_LINE_1=''WELLS STREET'' AND CITY=''HOLLYWOOD'' AND STATE=''IA'')

                            )
                            '

    --PRINT @SQLTEXT
    EXEC  (@SQLTEXT)

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify your code. ([mcve].)

Comment: It's this bit: `SELECT @dbn ,` you need quotes around the `@dbn` or it tries to select the db name as a column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely **not** the most efficient way to do this; most likely you should be using `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF` to do this.

Anyway, you need to parametrise your variable, and quote your dynamic objects. This results in the below:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempCounter (dbName1 sysname,
                           counterNumber1 int);

DECLARE @counter int = 1,
        @max int = 0,
        @dbName sysname,
        @count int = 0,
        @SQLTEXT nvarchar(MAX),
        @counterNumber varchar(10);

SELECT @max = COUNT(id)
FROM #tempPnamePadd;

WHILE @counter <= @max
BEGIN
    SET @dbName = '';

    -- Do whatever you want with each row in your table variable filtering by the Id column
    SELECT @dbName = name
    FROM #tempPnamePadd
    WHERE Id = @counter;

    PRINT @dbName;

    SET @SQLTEXT = N'INSERT INTO #tempCounter 
    (dbname1, counternumber1)
    SELECT @dbn ,
         (SELECT  count(*)
                                FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + N'.dbo.PRELA PR  
                            INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + N'.dbo.PNAME PN  
                            ON PR.NAME_ID = PN.NAME_ID  
                            INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + N'.dbo.PNALK NK  
                            ON PN.NAME_ID = NK.NAME_ID  
                            INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + N'.dbo.PADDR A  
                            ON NK.ADDRESS_ID = A.ADDRESS_ID  
                            WHERE (NAME_FORMAT_CODE=''B'' and NAME_BUSINESS like ''%BN'') OR
                            (NAME_FORMAT_CODE <> ''B'' and INDIVIDUAL_FIRST = ''John'') OR
                            (ADDR_LINE_1=''WELLS STREET'' AND CITY=''HOLLYWOOD'' AND STATE=''IA'')

                            )
                            ';

    --PRINT @SQLTEXT
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLTEXT, N'@dbn sysname', @dbn = @dbName;

    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END;
```

*Note I have also changed some of your data types.*

Answer (score 0):

You did not quote around `@dbName` in your dynamic query.
So instead of

```
 SET @dbn ='SP419001_SID';
```

you get

```
 SET @dbn =SP419001_SID;
```

Do

```
    'DECLARE @dbn VARCHAR(200)
    SET @dbn ='''+ @dbName +''';
    INSERT INTO #tempCounter 
    ...'
```

Comment: This is wide open to injection. You should be properly quoting your values in you're going to inject them.